# jQuery mobile detection and jQuery syntax

Tags: jquery, mobile, syntax

I'm new to javascript and jQuery so this might be a bit stupid question, i'm sorry for that.

I've made up a site that's working ok on mobile devices and on desktop but since my body:hover-based mobile detection wasn't a huge success after finding out that iDevices and some Android devices do their own tricks with :hover-selectors i've been trying to make a jQuery snippet that detects if user is not using any mobile devices and then adds class .hover to html body, adding some hover-effects to css.

My script-part looks like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {
        if(!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || !navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
            $("body").hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("hover")
            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass("hover")
            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

But it does not work. It works in my windows-firefox, adding the class .hover and enabling the hover-effects (and if i turn js off from browser properties it stops working, so i figured out that it really works?) but it does not work in iPhone. (I'm going to include also iPod, Android, Windows Phone etc. after this is working)

If I change the second last } (closing brace of if-statement) to }) it starts working in iPhone but stops working in Firefox.

Is there some bigger problems with this or am I just messing something up with js syntax? And is this also good way to do this kind of thing? Is there a way to do this with pure javascript so user wouldn't have to load whole jQuery library since I don't use it for anything else?

Thank you for replies (even those starting with 'you bloody idiot' (: ) I'm in quite of a hurry with this, otherwise I would have tried to get it myself for a few more hours. Also my first post to this site, so I would not mind to be corrected if I made some other mistakes with my post.

-Mikkå

Comment: Instead of browser sniffing, check whether browser supports touch events or not.